# What is the best way to read a structure from a binary file containing IP header fragments?

Tags: c++, c

During my computer networks lab, I had to read many binary files which contains the packet in IPv4 format. [Here](https://static.thegeekstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/ip-header-2.png) is the IPv4 header file format.

The following structure encapsulates all the essential part of the IP header.

```cpp
struct ip_header {
    uint8_t version;
    uint8_t header_length;
    uint8_t service_type;
    uint16_t total_length;
    uint16_t identification;
    uint8_t flags;
    uint16_t fragment_offset;
    uint8_t ttl;
    uint8_t protocol;
    uint16_t checksum;
    uint32_t src;
    uint32_t dest;
    /* other fields for options if needed */
};
```

One way to read the binary file to get the data in a structured format is to read the file bytes-by-bytes and then specifically typecast each byte field to respective fields for the above structure. Reading the file is not an issue.

I want to know whether this is the only way to do it, or is there any other nice and magical way to achieve the same. Also, recently I got know that endianness also creates some problem while reading these kinds of files with different sized data types.

Comment: c or c++ ? They are not the same. If c++, then what standard? Tag the one you are using (or none if you use the current one)

Comment: Also, the sizes of your fields are wrong. First one: `uint8_t version:4;` Use bit fields.

Comment: Since you've clarified that you know this is possible by reading raw bytes and casting to the correct types, have you tried anything else yet?

Comment: It would help if you made the struct in such a way that it is binary compatible with an actual IP header (minus the endianness). That way you can just read from the file straight into the memory belonging to `struct ip_header` variable. Have a look at `struct iphdr` in `/usr/include/netinet/ip.h`.

Comment: Thanks for the information @TedLyngmo.

Comment: Thanks @G.Sliepen, it was really helpful.

Comment: @KAUSHALKISHORE Usually you byte pack the struct (#pragma pack(1) or whatever your compiler uses) if you want the fields to match up with the data.  If you don't do that, there is a possibility of the fields not lining up with the data due to padding bytes placed in the struct.

Comment: Have you ever considered to use a boost.asio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual way is to use something like `fread`

```
bool readIpHeader(ip& buffer, const std::string& filename)
{
    auto pFile= fopen(filename.data(), "rb");
    if (!pFile) {
        return false;
    }
    auto ok= fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, pFile) == 1;
    fclose(pFile);
    return ok;
}
```

This will read `sizeof(buffer)` into address `&buffer`: it will fill the buffer with the contents of the file; `fread` will return 1 on success.

Like Ted pointed out, your structure is bad. You can take https://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/Net2/newsrc/netinet/ip.h.html as a source (most likely, you can `include` the file if you are on Linux):

```
struct ip {
#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN 
    u_char    ip_hl:4,           /* header length */
              ip_v:4;            /* version */
#endif
#if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN 
    u_char    ip_v:4,            /* version */
        ip_hl:4;        /* header length */
#endif
    u_char    ip_tos;            /* type of service */
    short     ip_len;            /* total length */
    u_short   ip_id;             /* identification */
    short     ip_off;            /* fragment offset field */
#define    IP_DF 0x4000          /* dont fragment flag */
#define    IP_MF 0x2000          /* more fragments flag */
    u_char    ip_ttl;            /* time to live */
    u_char    ip_p;              /* protocol */
    u_short   ip_sum;            /* checksum */
    struct    in_addr ip_src,ip_dst;    /* source and dest address */
};
```

Comment: AFAIK, bit field has no effect to remove paddings.

Comment: Thanks for the ip header structure @Mirko. But the issue was not to read the file. My question was: Is there any way in which I can directly read the structure from the binary file, in which case I wouldn't have to explicitly assign all the fields in the ip header structure.

Comment: The way I presented it you read all the structure at once in one line of code. You're not reading and assigning explicitly: it's done for you programmatically by the compiler.

Comment: @yumetodo I dont follow what you're saying. Who is talking about padding?

Comment: I concern about binary capability problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about portability—particularly with big-endian architectures that enforce natural alignment of 16-bit and 32-bit variables—you can’t just write the memory layout of your `struct` to disk.  The next release of the compiler might pack the data differently and break compatibility with all your data files.  And more than one big company has found out that they accidentally created two data formats, big-endian and little-endian, by compiling on another CPU and not normalizing.  Often, there wasn’t any easy way to tell which one an old file was saved in.  Remember, data outlives code!

This assumes that you want to use the `ip_header` structure within your program, it should be padded for efficient access, and that its purpose is not merely to shadow the file layout.

When the fields have different sizes interspersed together, there’s not a good way around setting them individually.  You cannot assume that the implementation can use an arbitrary, unaligned address as a pointer.  In this case, I also didn’t assume that the file has the same endianness as your CPU; I defined the byte order as big-endian.  (If you expect this code to run on a little-endian CPU like the x86, you might define the order as little-endian, but still code defensively by using a library such as [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.62/glib-Byte-Order-Macros.html) or the little-endian conversion functions of the OS.)

You can portably convert from a layout on disk to a structure in memory like so:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ip_header {
    uint8_t version;
    uint8_t header_length;
    uint8_t service_type;
    uint16_t total_length;
    uint16_t identification;
    uint8_t flags;
    uint16_t fragment_offset;
    uint8_t ttl;
    uint8_t protocol;
    uint16_t checksum;
    uint32_t src;
    uint32_t dest;
    /* other fields for options if needed */
} ip_header;

#define IP_HEADER_DISK_LEN 22U

bool read_ip_header( FILE* const input, ip_header* const d )
{
  char buffer[IP_HEADER_DISK_LEN];

  if ( IP_HEADER_DISK_LEN !=
       fread( buffer, 1, IP_HEADER_DISK_LEN, input ) ) {
    return false;
  }

  memset( d, 0, sizeof(*d) );

  memcpy( &d->version,         &buffer[0],  sizeof(d->version) );
  memcpy( &d->header_length,   &buffer[1],  sizeof(d->header_length) );
  memcpy( &d->service_type,    &buffer[2],  sizeof(d->service_type) );
  memcpy( &d->total_length,    &buffer[3],  sizeof(d->total_length) );
  d->total_length = ntohs(d->total_length);
  memcpy( &d->identification,  &buffer[5],  sizeof(d->identification) );
  d->identification = ntohs(d->identification);
  memcpy( &d->flags,           &buffer[7],  sizeof(d->flags) );
  memcpy( &d->fragment_offset, &buffer[8],  sizeof(d->fragment_offset) );
  d->fragment_offset = ntohs(d->fragment_offset);
  memcpy( &d->ttl,             &buffer[10], sizeof(d->ttl) );
  memcpy( &d->protocol,        &buffer[11], sizeof(d->protocol) );
  memcpy( &d->checksum,        &buffer[12], sizeof(d->checksum) );
  d->checksum = ntohs(d->checksum);
  memcpy( &d->src,             &buffer[14], sizeof(d->src) );
  d->src = ntohl(d->src);
  memcpy( &d->dest,            &buffer[18], sizeof(d->dest) );
  d->dest = ntohl(d->dest);

  return true;
}
```

This does a single read of the entire header, but you might do separate I/O calls, or even map the file into memory.  Most modern compilers are smart enough to combine consecutive `memcpy()` calls to consecutive locations, to compile unneeded byte-swaps to no-ops, and to only `memset()` bytes that won’t be overwritten immediately after, so, if you could get away with just copying the bytes, this way should be just as efficient.  (For your purposes, you could even skip zeroing-out the padding bytes and doing endian-conversion.)

Remember, the read operation will take much, much longer than any of the bit-twiddling to deal with alignment endianness, or padding.  Trying to optimize those is not a good use of your time.  Especially if it compiles to an incompatible program on another compiler!

Answer (score 2):

If your IPv4 headers are stored in the same format as "they came in" (which is the usual way to store them) - with source and destination address being the last fields in the header, this should do it:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <netinet/ip.h> // a common place to find a "iphdr" definition

// add a streaming operator for reading an iphdr
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, iphdr& ip) {
    return is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ip), sizeof(iphdr));
}

// add a streaming operator for writing an iphdr
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const iphdr& ip) {
    return os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&ip), sizeof(iphdr));
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream ips("ipheaders");
    if(ips) {
        iphdr h;
        while(ips >> h) {
            std::cout << h.version << "\n"
                      << h.ihl << "\n"
                      << h.tos << "\n"
                      << h.tot_len << "\n"
                      << h.id << "\n"
                      << h.frag_off << "\n"
                      << h.ttl << "\n"
                      << h.protocol << "\n"
                      << h.check << "\n"
                      << h.saddr << "\n"
                      << h.daddr << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The first 4 bits in the physical header is always `version` but as @Mirco showed, the endianness of the computer you compile the program for matters when you fiddle with bit fields. The first 4 bits coming through the network and that are stored in the file are still `version` - and will be if you write your `iphdr` to disk using the added `operator<<` too. If you want to be portable, read and write the IP headers exactly as they have looked since IPv4 was invented.

And luckily the layout of the ip header matches the alignment of the needed fundamental datatypes on the majority of systems. In case you find a system where it's not possible to create an IP header struct matching the raw data, you will most likely not find `netinet/ip.h` - but if you are still worried about it, you can add a compile time check:

```
    static_assert(alignof(uint8_t) == 1);
    static_assert(alignof(uint16_t) == 2);
    static_assert(alignof(uint32_t) == 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netinet/ip.h>
    ....
    #define IPSIZ  20
    static void ntoip(uint8_t *buf, struct ip *i) {
        i->ip_vhl = buf[0];
        i->ip_tos = buf[1];
        i->ip_len = ntohs(buf+2);
        i->ip_id  = ntohs(buf+4);
        i->ip_off = ntohs(buf+6);
        i->ip_ttl = buf[8];
        i->ip_p   = buf[9];
        i->ip_sum = ntohs(buf+10);
        i->ip_src = ntohl(buf+12);
        i->ip_dst = ntohl(buf+16);           
    }
    int fget_ip(FILE *fp, struct ip *i) {
        uint8_t buf[IPSIZ];
        if (fread(buf, sizeof buf, 1, fp) == 1) {
            ntoip(buf, i);
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
...
    void iptoh(struct ip *i, uint8_t *buf) {
...
    }
    int fput_ip(struct ip *i, FILE *fp) {
....
    }
```

is your best bet.  Simple, clear, easy to understand, portable.  You can make sure it is always read and stored in network order, that way it works whether from a file or an actual device.

If somehow it becomes a performance problem, it is encapsulated and you can replace it with the usual heap of shenanigans in one place.